# Air weight in bottle

Tags: experimental-physics

Does a closed water bottle full of air weigh more than an open water bottle? I have researched this, but no clear answer has shown up.

Comment: The water bottle has weight, and the air has weight.   The 'closed water bottle' can be weighed, and the known air mass subtracted, to give the weight of the bottle.

Comment: Does closing a jar of marbles cause it to weigh more? (assume that the lid is attached to the jar even when the jar is open.) Your question implies that you have some expectation that a jar of air would behave differently from a jar of marbles (perhaps, because the jar is at the bottom of a sea of air.) You might get more/better answers if you explain your expectation in more detail.

Comment: More intriguing question: Does a container weigh more at STP or during coastal hurricane pressure-temperature conditions?

Comment: @BillN, indeed, the bottle displaces air, so it experiences a small buoyant force.  I factored this into my weight and discovered that scales and balances read approximately 1/4 lb "short" due to this effect.

Comment: Except for the cap? No.

Comment: What is your weighting procedure? Becouse fro some serious weighting, aka balance calibrations, air bouyancy had to be calculated and took into account

Answer (score 0):

I would think not. The same amount of air is still going to be inside, and the amount of air inside is not likely going to increase over time. If you were to close the bottle at any given time, the same amount of air would still be inside at that exact time, closed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on many factors including the pressure at which you fill the bottle, the density of air where you weigh the bottle, the elevation where you weigh the bottle etc. But if you take an open bottle and weigh it and then close it and weigh it again keeping all the other conditions the same, then the weight would be the same if you include the weight of the cap or the seal in the weight of open bottle.

Answer (score 0):

## It depends on what you mean

#### Do you plan to use a bottle cap?

If you intend to close the bottle with a bottle cap then the answer is yes, adding a bottle cap to the bottle will increase its mass and thus also its weight.

#### Do you mean weight or perceived weight?

Weight according to the encyclopedia britannica means "Weight, gravitational force of attraction on an object, caused by the presence of a massive second object, such as the Earth or Moon."

And since we know the gravitational law to be

$F = G\frac{mM}{R^2} $

We know that closing a bottle won't change its weight although you could move it closer to the massive object or increase the mass of either the massive object or the bottle (bottle cap).

If you meant perceived weight then still closing the bottle won't instantly change the perceived weight, but you could get significant changes in the perceived weight - here on earth - without having to change $M$ or $R$ much at all.

To change the perceived weight of a sealed bottle all you have to do is push it underwater, you will feel a resisting force called buoyancy, which will cause you to perceive a negative weight. If you instead pushed an open bottle under, it would fill with water and the buoyancy would be negligible.

#### Is the contained air considered part of the bottle

If so, there is another fun thing you can do. If you would flatten the bottle (pushing out most air), the total weight of the bottle and the air it contains would change.

However, doing so would not change the perceived weight because the added weight of the air inside the bottle exactly cancels out with the perceived negative weight the buoyancy of this air creates. Thus, it would be heavier on a technicality but it would not be perceivably so.

## So, kind of no

The weight won't change unless you plan to use a bottle cap or change the environment in which the bottle resides.